# There is methodX in Interface I, class C1 & C2 use the exact code of methodX, so where to put the Logic into methodX? (Java)

Tags: java

Ok, I have class C1 & C2, both already extends other Class

```
public class C1 extends M{
    public double calCost(double price, int qty){
        return price*qty;
    }
}

public class C2 extends N{
    public double calCost(double price, int qty){
        return price*qty;
    }
}
```

In fact, my `calCost` is very complicated, so I don't want to duplicate the exact code calCost cos it very difficult to maintain.

So, I knew we need to use Interface like

```
interface Calculation{
    public void calCost();
}
```

& then we do like `public class C1 extends M implements Calculation` & `public class C2 extends M implements Calculation`, but then we still have to duplicate the same logic of `calCost` in C1 & C2. So,

Where to put the logic of `calCost` so that we don't need to duplicate?

Other solution is using Utility static methods but this is not good for Unit Test as someone said.

Comment: Might not answer your question straight forward, but you may be interested in Java 8's Interface default methods. Where it allows us to have a default implementation of a method with in an interface http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use something known as an `abstract class`.

```
abstract class Calculation {
    public int calCost(int x, int y) {
        // put your long definition here
        return x + y;
    }
}

class FirstCalc extends Calculation {
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        int c = calCost(a, b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

You could also make `calCost` an `abstract` method, if you'd like each class that extends the `Calculation` class to define their own implementations.

Or, use composition:

```
class Calculation { 
    public int calCost(int x, int y) { 
        return x + y; //or other implementation 
    }
}

class C1 extends M {
    private Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        int c = calculation.calCost(a, b);
    }
}

class C2 extends M {
    private Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
    public void someOtherOtherMethod() {
        // ...
        int c = calculation.calCost(10, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: but i can't extend 2 class, C1 already extends N, so I can't do "C1 extends N, Calculation?"

Comment: Why not have a single class `Calculation` with a single purpose, `calCost`, and use an instance as a member in any classes that require it?

Comment: What u mean? C1 already extends N, N is an Built-in Java class & i can't modify N

Comment: so u mean u can make interface extending a an abstract class?

Comment: Updated. You could merely refactor the long method into it's own class, then create instances in each of your other classes as you need them.

Comment: Actually, no. Composition is merely using objects within other objects. A utility class is more of a stateless class with utility methods. You could also use one in this case (ex. `CalcUtils.calCost()`), but I prefer composition.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a abstract class to implement calCost and let C1 and C2 extend this.

```
public abstract class CA extends M {
    public double calCost(double price, int qty){
        return price*qty;
    }
}

public class C1 extends CA {
    ....
}

public class C2 extends CA {
    ....
}
```

Since CA is abstract you do not need to override any other method and the implementation of all other methods can be handled by C1 and C2 separatly.

Comment: But I can't do "C1 extends N, Calculation"  ?

Comment: M is an built-in Java class & I can't modify that buit-in class

Comment: Extending is only possible for 1 parent class, implementing may be done for multiple interfaces. But since CA extends M and C1 extends CA, C1 is an Object of the class M as well. To user your Calculation Interface you may let CA implement Calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just saw, that C1 and C2 extend 2 different classes M and N. So there is no way to merge both classes together. If M and N inherit from the same Class and all needed Methods are defined in this parent Class, generics may help you, but without any more details on your real code I can't tell you if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You already extending your classes with two different classes. 
You don't need to depend on `IS-A` all the times. You can create another instance class and push you `calCost` to that by passing appropriate parameters and have an `HAS-A` association.

Also, in Java 8 interfaces will allow us to have a default implementation for a method. It might not be a problem in future. Here is a quick link to follow http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/